# A way to find Magento credit card information?

Tags: magento

A customer on my Magento site recently purchased an item with a disposable credit card. Long story short, we refunded the client and they had destroyed the card so they are unable to receive the money.

I was wondering if there is a way in Magento to retrieve full credit card numbers from purchases, so the client can contact the card company?  We are using Authorize.net as our payment gateway.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably contact Authorize.net to see if they can help you out manually.  I believe that the Authorize.net payment method does not store credit cards - the Saved Credit Card payment method may store them out of the box.

But you should know that it's not advisable to store credit cards yourself, and a violation of PCI compliance in general.